# How to set and change color of date on calendar using FullCalender in Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying set start date and end date on calendar in Angular using FullCalender.Currently I have an object which has start date and end date. I want to add color from start date to end date. https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo

I tried using valid range but I can iterate through object?

In HTML:

```
<div class='app-calendar' *ngFor="let item of calendarscheduledEvents">

  <full-calendar
  #calendar
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  [header]="{
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  }"
[validRange] = "{
        start: item.start,
        end: item.end
      }"
  [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
  [weekends]="calendarWeekends"
  [events]="calendarEvents"
  (dateClick)="openModal(template,$event)"
></full-calendar>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; // the #calendar in the template

calendarVisible = true;
calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin,listPlugin];
calendarWeekends = true;
calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [];
toggleVisible() {
    this.calendarVisible = !this.calendarVisible;
}
toggleWeekends() {
    this.calendarWeekends = !this.calendarWeekends;
}

gotoPast() {
    let calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
    calendarApi.gotoDate('2000-01-01'); // call a method on the Calendar object
}
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template,{
        class: 'modal-dialog-centered'
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example on Stack Blitz as a starting point? Then it's easier to help you.

Comment: "trying set start date and end date" ...of what? Your events? The date range visible to the user? The date range allowed for events to be created? Something else? Please be clear and precise about your requirement. Unsurprisingly, fullCalendar is full of dates for all kinds of purposes, so you need to tell us exactly what you are referring to. Thanks.

Comment: I have an object which has start date and end date. I want to set these start date and end date on calender I tried using valid range but that works only I add hard coded values. I tried iterating using ngfor but it is not working.

Comment: so you want to set the validRange property? Ok. Please show the actual code you tried, then, and also explain the meaning of "not working" - do you mean there is an error? Or some unexpected outcome? Please be clear and specific.  We can't see what you did wrong unless we can see the code and get a proper problem report. I'm not an Angular expert but I will do my best to help, and perhaps someone else also will be able to help. The only sure thing though is that we cannot fix invisible code.

Comment: I have added demo link in my question.

Comment: where in the demo is the validRange code? I can't see it.

Comment: And what do you mean by "iterate the object" exactly? The object you've shown for validRange only has one set of properties. it isn't an array.